# JMeter showing different request time

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have written a script where I have combined 10 HTTP requests with the number of threads different for each but the same Ramp Up period set to 1 second. I had a look at the Kibana after the test execution. What I can see is that the API requests are requested in 5 seconds even though the Ramp Up period is set to 1 second. The command which I used to generate the graphs and results file is as below.

```
jmeter -n -t S:\roshTests\Cocktail\Cocktail.jmx -l S:\roshTests\Cocktail\results.csv
```

Even the results.CSV file shows the timestamp of a gap between 5 seconds.

Can someone answer me the following?

a) Does the results.CSV file shows the response time or the time it requested by Jmeter?

b) Few threads are in 1000 range and few are less than 100. Is there any restriction for the maximum threads that can be applied in a second using JMeter?

c) Why the results.CSV shows a gap of 5 seconds with Ramp Up set to 1 second.

d) Is there any Graph which shows that the requests are sent in a second?

Comment: May I ask you why the ramp up is 1 second? Don't you have to give some time to the server to process your requests. Good real-world scenario will have some ramp-up time. Have you monitored the performance in the `summarizer`? Based on your system configuration there is a limit to run the number of threads. `Request Summary` is available here http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html

Comment: Naveen.. For testing the performance my requirement is to check how many requests can be processed in a second. How do i check the summarizer?